# How to add expiry date in HUEY dynamic periodic task just like in celery tasks?

Tags: django, cron, django-celery, periodic-task, python-huey

**Is there a way to add expiry date to a Huey Dynamic periodic task ?**
Just like there is an option in celery task - "some_celery_task.apply_async(args=('foo',), expires=expiry_date)"
to add expiry date while creating the task.

I want to add the expiry date while creating the Huey Dynamic periodic task. I used "revoke" , it worked as it supposed to , but I want to stop the task completely after the expiry date not revoking it . When the Huey dynamic periodic task is revoked - message is displayed on the Huey terminal that the huey function is revoked (whenever crontab condition becomes true).
(I am using Huey in django)

(Extra)
What I did to meet the need of this expiry date -
I created the function which return Days - Months pairs for crontab :
For eg.
start date = 2021-1-20 , end date = 2021-6-14
then the function will return - Days_Month :[['20-31',1], ['*','2-5'], ['1-14','6']]
Then I call the Huey Dynamic periodic task (three times in this case).
(the Days_Month function will return Day-Months as per requirement - Daily, Weekly, Monthly or repeating after n days)

**Is there a better way to do this?**
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please format code and point out the code fragments

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will depend on how often you need this functionality of having periodic tasks with a specific end date but the ideal approach is probably involving your database.

I would create a database model (let's call it `Job`) with fields for your `end_date`, a `next_execution_date` and a field that indicates the `interval` between repetitions (like x days).

You would then create a periodic task with huey that runs every day (or even every hour/minute if you need finer grain of control). Every time this periodic task runs you would then go over all your `Job` instances and check whether their `next_execution_date` is in the past. If so, launch a new huey task that actually executes the functionality you need to have periodically executed per `Job` instance. On success, you calculate the new `next_execution_date` using the `interval`.

So whenever you want a new `Job` with a new `end_date`, you can just create this in the django admin (or make an interface for it) and you would set the `next_execution_date` as the first date where you want it to execute.

Your final solution would thus have the `Job` model and two huey decorated functions. One for the periodic task that merely checks whether `Job` instances need to be executed and updates their `next_execution_date` and another one that actually executes the periodic functionality per `Job` instance. This way you don't have to do any manual cancelling and you only need 1 periodic task that just runs indefinitely but doesn't actually execute anything if there are no `Job` instances that need to be run.

Note: this will only be a reasonable approach if you have multiple of these tasks and you potentially want to control the `end_date`s in your interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its really very efficient. I implemented your solution and its working great.

Comment: Glad I could help!